# SOQL query to get all accounts where none of related contact has useful information

Tags: salesforce, soql

I would like to export a list of Accounts where ALL of its Contacts are empty of information as phone, email, etc.

I wrote:

```
SELECT Id, Name, typ_av_konto__c, Malm__c,
    (SELECT Name FROM Contacts WHERE phone = NULL AND Email = Null )
FROM Account
WHERE Malm__c = True AND IsDeleted = False AND typ_av_konto__c = 'Brf/Bf' AND e_post__c = Null
```

But I get Accounts where Contacts has any information. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want:

- Accounts that have contacts (so not "widows", Accounts that don't have any contacts)
- But all of these contacts must be empty-ish (no phone, no email...)

You can make it happen with "semi joins" and "[anti joins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)"

> Sample uses of semi-joins and anti-joins include:
>
> - Get all contacts for accounts that have an opportunity with a
>   particular record type.
> - Get all open opportunities for accounts that have active contracts.
> - Get all open cases for contacts that are the decision maker on an opportunity.
> - Get all accounts that don’t have any open opportunities.

```sql
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Account
WHERE
    Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
    AND Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email != null OR Phone != null)

    AND Malm__c = true
    AND typ_av_konto__c = 'Brf/Bf'
    AND e_post__c = null
```

In the SF sample data (you know, the kind you can find in Developer Edition, Trailhead playgrounds etc; "GenePoint", "Burlington Textiles", "University of Arizona"...) without your custom fields this query returns "sForce". Looks good, there are 2 contacts but they're poor quality all right:

[image]

If you consider "widows" interesting too (accounts that have poor quality contacts and accounts that have no contacts at all) - drop the `Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact) AND` part.

Comment: Im gonna edit it now. I meant: List of accounts that ALL its contacts are empty of information (No phone, no email, etc)

Comment: O, clearer, thx. Try with 2 cross filters. Im on mobile now, will revisit later. "Where Id in (select AccountId from contact) and id not in (select accountid from contact where email !=null or phone !=null)"